# Background Service in ionic 1 Taking too much battery consumption

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, background, battery

I am creating an IONIC application for Android & iOS.
As per my requirement, I need to call background service in every 3 hours interval.
I am using [cordova-plugin-background-mode cordoava plugin](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode).
I am using following code for background:

```
      document.addEventListener('deviceready', function () {

        // Enable background mode
        cordova.plugins.backgroundMode.enable();
        // cordova.plugins.backgroundMode.setEnabled(true);
        // Called when background mode has been activated
        cordova.plugins.backgroundMode.setDefaults({ silent: true });

        cordova.plugins.backgroundMode.on('activate', function () {
             interval = setInterval(function () {

         **//Doing background stuff: Using Bluetooth BLE.**

        }, milliseconds); 

    }, false);
```

In IOS, If i check my battery status it shows: **e.g. 5 hours in background & 5  minutes on screen**

Battery drains in approx 5-6 hours. I have checked all the possibilities for optimize it but i am not able to get succeed.

Apart from that I have checked it in Android as well. Result is same.

I have check any other plug-ins as well but i am not getting any other best plugin in cordova for battery optimization in background.

Kindly help me for this. & please provide your valuable suggestion around this.
What are the possibilities for background in cordava & ionic? 
can someone suggest on this?